# pthread_cancel returning EINPROGRESS

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, posix, cancellation

I am maintaining some code right now, that creates a pthread with `pthread_create()`. This thread also calls `pthread_detach(pthread_self());` soon after creation. Furthermore it uses `pthread_cleanup_push()` to push a clean-up handler. The only cancellation point of this thread is a call to `pthread_testcancel()` at the end of the threads main loop.

I now see, that at some point `pthread_cancel()` gets called on this thread and (almost) always returns a nonzero value. Checking errno results in `EINPROGRESS`. What exactly does this mean? Because the man pages states

> On success, pthread_cancel() returns 0

However, it also mentions,

> that cancellation will be delayed until the thread next calls a function that is a cancellation point.

So if a return value of nonzero and errno equal to `EINPROGRESS` means, that the cancellation request got queued, but was not yet reacted upon, I would expect that to be always the case. But if a return value of 0 indicates success, then it must mean something different.

What does `EINPROGRESS` mean in this circumstance and how can I make sure, that the thread got canceled correctly or was already terminated?

---

I am running Debian 7.4 with libpthread-2.13 as part of libc6:amd64 2.13-38+deb7u1 in a VM.

Comment: On which platform, using which version/implementation of PThreads do you observe this behaviour?

Comment: You immediately check errno after the cancel call and only if the return code was non-zero?  EINPROGRESS isn't a valid error and assuming pthread_cancel is implemented as a signal there is no real progress to be monitored.

Comment: Yep, this is what the code does. Sorry, my question was wrong in the way, that I said that EINPROGRESS was *returned*. In fact a non-zero value is returned and errno is set to EINPROGRESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I now see, that at some point pthread_cancel() gets called on this thread and (almost) always returns a nonzero value. Checking errno results in EINPROGRESS.

The `pthread*` family of functions does not set `errno`, but instead returns the error code as function value.

So do not only test the outcome of the call to `pthread_cancel()` against `0`, but actually interpret the value returned as what you "normaly" find in `errno`, that is one of the `E*` error values.

```
int result = pthread_cancel(<some-pthread>);
if (0 != result)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "pthread_cancel() failed with error #%d: '%s'\n", result, strerror(result)); /* Better use strerror_r() in a multithreaded enviroment. */
}
```

Btw: Inspecting the sources of the libc you seem to be using does not reveal any hints of `pthread_cancel()` returning `EINPROGRESS`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I took the existing code for granted and overlooked that pthread_cancel indeed does not set errno. I will have to check the actual return code...

Comment: Ok, the actual return value is telling me "No such process" what was caused by some other issue. Accepting this as answer since it made me find out the actual cause of my problem and pointed out another bug in the code.

Answer (score 0):

A thread's cancelability state, determined by pthread_setcancelstate(3), can be enabled (the default for new threads) or disabled. If a thread has disabled cancellation, then a cancellation request remains queued until the thread enables cancellation. If a thread has enabled cancellation, then its cancelability type determines when cancellation occurs.

```
-
```

A thread's cancellation type, determined by pthread_setcanceltype(3), may be either asynchronous or deferred (the default for new threads). Asynchronous cancelability means that the thread can be canceled at any time (usually immediately, but the system does not guarantee this). Deferred cancelability means that cancellation will be delayed until the thread next calls a function that is a cancellation point.

```
EINPROGRESS:
```

An operation that cannot complete immediately was initiated on an object that has non-blocking mode selected. Some functions that must always block (such as connect) never return EAGAIN; instead, they return EINPROGRESS to indicate that the operation has begun and will take some time. Attempts to manipulate the object before the call completes return EALREADY.

```
...how can I make sure, that the thread got canceled correctly 
or was already terminated?
```

You can use the select function to find out when the pending operation has completed.

Comment: You mean, that for a canceltype of deferred or a cancelstate of disabled, it is totally fine and expected that pthread_cancel() returns nonzero and errno equals EINPROGRESS? Actually this would make sense, although I find the man page a bit misleading then.

Comment: Could you explain how one can use select() to wait for the termination of a detached pthread?